# SSAS Tabular Model occasionally takes hours to process

Tags: performance, ssas-tabular

I have a fairly large tabular model and most days it only takes 8-10 minutes but every few days it will take 4-5 hours. Where would I even being to start troubleshooting this. I looked at the ETL logs but all it shows me is the step that asks the model to be processed.

Someone mentioned seeing if it was processing in parallel mode or sequential but I can't seem to find any setting for that in VS 2017 which is what I'm using.

I should also mention that I manually process it, it takes the normal amount of time (8-10 minutes). It's only when the ETL to process it executes that I sometimes see this long processing time.

Comment: Can you share the code which is automating the processing of the model? Is it a process full of the whole database or something more incremental like only processing recent partitions?

Comment: Do you have any perfmon logs from the server? Is the server dedicated only to SSAS Tabular or are their multiple SQL or other services on there potentially competing for memory?